# How can I create a list of plots to be rendered with ggplot?

Tags: r, list, ggplot2, gridextra

I am trying to construct a list of ggplot graphics, which will be plotted later.  What I have so far, using Anscombe's quartet for an example, is:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
base <- ggplot() + xlim(4,19)
plots = vector(mode = "list", length = 4)
for(i in 1:4) {
  x <- anscombe[,i]
  y <- anscombe[,i+4]
  p <- geom_point(aes(x,y),colour="blue")
  q <- geom_smooth(aes(x,y),method="lm",colour="red",fullrange=T)
  plots[[i]] <- base+p+q
}
grid.arrange(grobs = plots,ncol=2)
```

As I travel through the loop, I want the current values of the plots p and q to be added with the base plot, into the i-th value of the list.  That is, so that list element number i contains the plots relating to the i-th x and y columns from the dataset.

However, what happens is that the last plot only is drawn, four times.  I've done something very similar with base R, using `mfrow`, `plot` and `abline`, so that I believe my logic is correct, but my implementation isn't.  I suspect that the issue is with these lines:

```
plots = vector(mode = "list", length = 4)
plots[[i]] <- base+p+q
```

How can I create a list of ggplot graphics; starting with an empty list?

(If this is a trivial and stupid question, I apologise.  I am very new both to R and to the Grammar of Graphics.)

Answer (score 1):

The code works properly if `lapply()` is used instead of a for loop.

```r
plots <- lapply(1:4, function(i) { 
  # create plot number i
})
```

The reason for this issue is that ggplot uses lazy evaluation. By the time the plots are rendered, the loop already iterated to `i=4` and the last plot will be displayed four times.

Full working example:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
base <- ggplot() + xlim(4,19)
plots <- lapply(1:4, function(i) {
  x <- anscombe[,i]
  y <- anscombe[,i+4]
  p <- geom_point(aes(x,y),colour="blue")
  q <- geom_smooth(aes(x,y),method="lm",colour="red",fullrange=T)
  base+p+q
})
grid.arrange(grobs = plots,ncol=2)
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  Again, the subtle difference between looping and applying (or "lapplying") is one that I am very unclear on.  More to learn...

Answer (score 0):

To force evaluation, there's a simple solution, change `aes(...)` into `aes_(...)` and your code works.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
base <- ggplot() + xlim(4,19)
plots <- lapply(1:4, function(i) {
  x <- anscombe[,i]
  y <- anscombe[,i+4]
  p <- geom_point(aes_(x,y),colour="blue")
  q <- geom_smooth(aes_(x,y),method="lm",colour="red",fullrange=T)
  base+p+q
})
grid.arrange(grobs = plots,ncol=2)
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks!  I was not aware of the difference between `aes` and `aes_`.  So many things to learn... such a tiny brain to squeeze them into...